# spring data Elasticsearch dynamic mapping

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Given using annotation on both Class and fields levels to set my mappings settings and use settings file like this

> @Setting(settingPath = "settings.json")

to define custom analyzers, how would I set mappings **"dynamic": false** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `dynamic` mapping type on document and objects was introduced in Spring Data Elasticsearch version 4.0.0. It can be defined like this (code from the tests):

```
@Document(indexName = "test-index-configure-dynamic-mapping")
@DynamicMapping(DynamicMappingValue.False)
class ConfigureDynamicMappingEntity {

    @Nullable 
    @DynamicMapping(DynamicMappingValue.Strict) 
    @Field(type = FieldType.Object) 
    private Author author;

    @Nullable
    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have link for the whole repo?

Comment: The library is available in maven/gradle, the repo is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch. Make sure you use the right versions of Elasticsearch and possibly Spring Bott (see  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#preface.versions)